# How to apply this particular style to an input

Tags: html, css

How can I apply a style to a text field that displays only one line at the bottom , which disappears as you type ? I must use only css.

i mean someting like this

_surname____________

_my name____________

i've tryed this, but this is only alf of the job because line doesn't disapper

```
input[type="text"]
{
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: Add your code as well what you have tried.

Comment: ok, i've added the code

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type="text"]
{
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    outline: 0;
    background-color:transparent;
    padding:4px;
    line-height:1;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: ok, but can i delete only where the user write like this: _test_____

Comment: Not possible with only `css`.